# using getClass() relection method to output name of class

Tags: java, reflection

I am tring to get the class to print its own name using getClass(). i want it to include the package name too. the package is called "reflections" and the class is called ReflectionClass. This is what I have so far!

```
package reflections;
public class ReflectionClass {
    public void className(){
        String name = reflections.ReflectionClass.getClass().getName();
        System.out.print(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your current solution does not suit your needs?

Comment: .getClass().getPackage()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
String className = this.getClass().getName();
System.out.println(className);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

[getCanonicalName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getCanonicalName())

or

[getPackage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getPackage())

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

```
System.out.print((new ReflectionClass()).getClass().getName());
```

Because you cant reffer non-static method `getClass()` in static way.

**Method 2**

> It is also possible to get the Class object for a named type (or for
>   void) using a class literal (JLS Section 15.8.2). For example:

```
System.out.println(ReflectionClass.class.getName());
```

Comment: That is useful to know about getClass() being non-static.  Thank you